# The scaled width calculation using Fabric js returns incorrect values

Tags: node.js, fabricjs

I have an application in Node.js that uses the `node-fabric` library [(npmjs.com/package/fabric)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric) to generate images from text and custom fonts from Google. The canvas I create has a width of 1024 and a height of 256.

The issue I'm facing is with the `getScaledWidth()` method of the text object, when using a custom font, `getScaledWidth()` returns an incorrect value, causing the rendered text to be wider than the canvas width.

For example: before rendering, the width is 90% (912 < 1024) of the canvas width, but when I render I realize that it is more than 120% (1284 > 1024).

I have registered the custom font using `fabric.nodeCanvas.registerFont()`, and I can successfully use the font for rendering text. However, the measured width of the text using `getScaledWidth()` is inaccurate.

I am still not 100% sure that the issue occurs specifically with custom fonts, but, the problem doesn't arise when using default system fonts.

Here's a simplified version of the code that reproduces the issue:

```
    //
    fabric.nodeCanvas.registerFont(font_path, { family: `${font_family}`, weight: 'regular', style: 'normal' });

    //
    const text_object = new fabric.Text("Username goes here...", { 
        fill: 'red', 
        fontFamily: font_family,
        backgroundColor: 'blue'
    });

    // 
    const project_image_canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas(null, { width: 1024, height: 256, backgroundColor: 'yellow' });
    const maximum_width = 512;

    // Calculate font size so the canvas includes all of the text width
    let font_size = 300;
    text_object.set({ fontSize: font_size, angle: 0, });
    while (text_object.getScaledWidth() > maximum_width) {
        font_size -= 5;
        text_object.set({ fontSize: font_size, });
    }

    //
    project_image_canvas.add(text_object);
    project_image_canvas.renderAll();
```

I have already tried setting the `originX` and `originY` properties of the `text_object` to `center`, but it doesn't solve the issue. I'm looking for a solution or workaround to accurately measure the width of the text when using custom fonts.

The attached screenshot depicts the issue. Based on the provided code, my expectation is to have all the texts contained within the boundaries of the blue rectangle. However, as shown in the screenshots, the texts extend beyond the expected boundaries.

[image]